# Imported, Exploded Word List Doesn't Compare Properly

Tags: php, arrays, string, comparison

My original test implementation consisted of building an array of "ignore words" with the following code:

```
$ignoreList = array("test1", "test2", "test3");
```

Later on, I test for individual words in the $ignoreList:

```
if(in_array($word, $ignoreList)){
    } else{
    $words[$word] = $words[$word] + 1;
}
```

This code works perfectly - upon later echoing my word list, no words on the $ignoreList show up.  I refactored to make it easier to add or remove words:

```
//Import ignore list
$ignore_raw = file_get_contents("includes/ignore.txt");
$ignoreList = explode("\n", $ignore_raw);
```

ignore.txt is a plain text file with each item on its own line, no spaces.  The import and explode seems to be working, because a print_r statement on $ignoreList results in:

```
Array ( [0] => a [1] => and [2] => are [3] => as [4] => for [5] => in [6] => is [7] => more [8] => of [9] => than [10] => that [11] => the [12] => to [13] => with )
```

The comparison code, however, stops working properly, and words on the ignore list show up once again in my final results.  Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: what does var_dump say? suppose you made the txt file in notepad, which uses \r\n for line returns, and \r is left at the end of each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ignore.txt file may have `\r\n` line endings, and your words actually have a trailing `\r`.

Try that:

```
$ignoreList = array_map('trim', file("includes/ignore.txt"));
```

BTW your code may be refactored like that:

```
$words = array_diff($words, $ignoreList); // removes ignored words
$words = array_count_values($words); // count words
```

Comment: That did it.  As a follow-up - any particular reason print_r doesn't show the trailing line endings?